# Correct syntax for `min/max width` + `not (device type)` CSS media queries

Tags: css

What the correct syntax for below media query?

```
@media (min-width: 960px) and not print
```

The following media query

```
@media print and (min-width: 960px)
```

is valid. Same for `@media not print and (min-width: 960px)`, but the "not" keyword is affecting to both `print` and `(min-width: 960px)`. I want to exclude only `print`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#inverting_a_querys_meaning: _"The `not` keyword inverts the meaning of an entire media query. [...] **The `not` keyword can't be used to negate an individual feature query, only an entire media query.**"_

Comment: But `not (min-width)` should be "translatable" into `(max-width)`.

Comment: The target is not really clear... what exactly are you targeting?

Comment: @Salketer I need the grid layout on wide screens, but only for non-print devices. For either narrow screens or print devices, I need another layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to target narrow screens and print devices:

```
@media print or (max-width: 960px)
```

You need to target the rest:

```
@media not print and (max-width: 960px)
```

The first one, targets anything that is print or below 960px wide. The second will target anything non print that is wider than 960px

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Accept & upvote.